# css: flex - вычисление ширины элементов для заполнения всей ширины родительского элемента

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Подскажите, как можно с использованием flex сделать так, чтобы элементы были такой длины, чтобы заполнять всю ширину блока

Например, у меня есть блок

```
<div>
    <div class = 'b1'></div>
    <div class = 'b2'></div>
    <div class = 'b3'></div>
    <div class = 'b4'></div>
    <div class = 'b5'></div>
</div>
```

блоки `b1` И `b5` имеют заданную ширину, а остальные должны быть такой ширины, чтобы заполнить весь родительский блок

Подскажите как это модно с помощью flex сделать, а то что-то туплю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body>div {
  display: flex;
}

div>div {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  flex: 1;
}

.b1,
.b5 {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='b1'></div>
  <div class='b2'></div>
  <div class='b3'></div>
  <div class='b4'></div>
  <div class='b5'></div>
</div>
```